# Need xpath locators for visible elements

Tags: python, xpath, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make a test for my site. Having troubles on some user form. The trick is, that the number of text fields in the form varies depending in user options (disabled ones are present in the code, but have a style <`displayed: none;`> tag), so I'm trying to find more flexible approach than locating every element one-by-one and filling the forms with try/except blocks.

I'm using an xpath locator

`text_fields = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='form-line']/div[@class='form-inputs']/input[@type='text' and not(ancestor::div[@style='display: none;'])]")`

The trouble is that firebug locates only needed elements, but when I use it my selenium script, printing the list of `text_fields` gives me all the elements, even without a <`displayed: none;`> tag

How can I get only visible elements?

PS Sorry for my bad English ^_^

Comment: is injecting jQuery and using the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector an alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all the form elements the usual way, then iterate on the list and remove those elements that do not return true on [`is_displayed()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try the `contains()` method:

```
text_fields = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
  "//div[@class='form-line']/div[@class='form-inputs']/input[@type='text' and 
  not(ancestor::div[contains(@style, 'display: none;')])]")
```

The important part is:

```
div[contains(@style, 'display: none;')]
```

Note, that if the style contains the string `display:none;` or `display:none`, the selector won't match.

Comment: I forgot to mention, but I tried _contains()_ method first. Same story

Answer (score -1):

I use the following and it works great.

```
self.assertTrue(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='game_icons']/div/div[2]/div/a/img"))
```

This is for Selenium and Python of course.

Comment: Ho does the assertTrue ensures that the element is visible? PLease explain